# angular binning using healpy

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, healpy

Let's say I have three quantities: theta, phi and v(theta,phi). I would like to use angular binning so that I can interpolate any future theta & phi to get v. I am completely new to healpix and don't understand how to go about doing this. Essentially I would like a grid of theta and phi and then would like to use scipy.griddata for interpolation. Thanks.

Comment: have you had a look at [numpy.histogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could just use interpolation with `scipy.interpolate.interp2d`, see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html, without even using `healpy`.

However, let me show how you would do that using a `healpy` map. The idea is that you precompute `v(theta,phi)` for each pixel of a map, then for future `theta` and `phi` you find which pixel they belong to and get the map value at that pixel very quickly with `healpy`.

See my notebook here: https://gist.github.com/zonca/e16fcf42e23e30fb2bc7301482f4683f

I copied the code below for reference:

```
import healpy as hp
import numpy as np

NSIDE = 64

print("Angular resolution is {:.2f} arcmin".format(hp.nside2resol(NSIDE, arcmin=True)))
NPIX = hp.nside2npix(NSIDE)
print("Number of pixels", NPIX)
pixel_indices = np.arange(NPIX)
theta_pix, phi_pix = hp.pix2ang(NSIDE, pixel_indices)
def v(theta, phi):
    return theta ** 2
v_map = v(theta_pix, phi_pix)
new_theta, new_phi = np.radians(30), np.radians(0)
new_pix = hp.ang2pix(NSIDE, new_theta, new_phi)
print("New theta and phi are hitting pixel", new_pix)
# We find what pixel the new coordinates are hitting and get the precomputed value of V at that pixel, to increase accuracy, you can increase NSIDE of the precomputed map.
v_map[new_pix]
v(new_theta, new_phi)
```